# How do I convert less than 8 bytes to a ulong in C#?

Tags: c#, byte, bitconverter, ulong

So I am implementing a cryptography algorithm now. 
And I need to convert data to bytes and then split it in 64 bits. I do it by using BitConverter.
But sometimes I don't have 8 bytes in the end of a message and I wonder how to convert less than 8 bytes to ulong.

Is there any way to do it using BitConverter? I tried shifting the bytes but it's too complicated since I don't know the exact amount of bytes.

Comment: You need 8 bytes for a 64bit variable. If you have less than 8 and still want 64 bits, fill them up with zero bytes from the left until you have 8 bytes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fill the byte array with *0s* until it fits the size required.

```
byte[] bytes = new byte[255]{ 0x1F, 0x1A, 0x1B, 0x2C, 0x3C, 0x6D, 0x1E }; //7 bytes

while(bytes.Length < 8){
   bytes.Concat(new byte[] { 0x00 });
}

long res = BitConverter.ToUInt64(bytes, 0);
```

Reference:

- [BitConverter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.bitconverter.touint64%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: `.Concat()` does not modify the array. It just creates an `IEnumerable` that iterates over both arrays. This example might seem to work, since `bytes.Length == 255`, and the `while`-loop is skipped.
To extend an array, you have to either use `Array.Resize`, or create a new array, and copy over the data.